# How to create only one sitemap in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using `next-sitemap` package for creating sitemap.
I have dynamic and static pages.

this is my `next-sitemap.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    siteUrl: 'https://example.com',
    generateRobotsTxt: false,
    exclude: ['/server-sitemap-index.xml'], // <= exclude here
    robotsTxtOptions: {
      additionalSitemaps: [
        'https://example.com/server-sitemap-index.xml', // <==== Add here
      ],
    },
  }
```

but this config generate two sitemaps.

`robots.txt`:

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

content of above link:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<script/>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap-0.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/server-sitemap-index.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

`sitemap-0.xml` is static links and `server-sitemap-index.xml` is dynamic links.

but I want to have only one site map for example:

https://example.com/sitemap.xml

```
static links
....
dynamic links
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on their documentation you can opt out of having multiple sitemaps -

> From next-sitemap v2.x onwards, sitemap.xml will be Index Sitemap.
> It will contain urls of all other generated sitemap endpoints.
>
> Index sitemap generation can be turned off by setting
> generateIndexSitemap: false in next-sitemap config file. (This is
> useful for small/hobby sites which does not require an index sitemap)
> (Example: no-index-sitemaps)

```
generateIndexSitemap: false
```

https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap